# Is there a way to pass the export password directly to the command?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, openssl, keytool

To automate the process of SSL certificate deployment, I need information whether the export password and then the security password can be provided directly in the command without the need to enter it in input?

The commands it uses:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in domain.crt -inkey domain.key -certfile root.crt -out domain.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore domain.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore domain.jks
```

It's working only after i've enter password in input but i must enter password directly in command.

Thanks and greetings.

Comment: This is not about programming or development and is not suitable for StackOverflow, but both `openssl pkcs12` and `keytool -importkeystore` have options to provide passwords as options on commandline described in their respective man pages and manuals, and summarized in their 'usage' messages, just do `openssl pkcs12 -help` and `keytool -help -importkeystore`. Also note Java 9 up _recommends_ using PKCS12 instead of legacy, restricted, and weak JKS, and Java 8 since 8u60 or so fully _supports_ PKCS12 although it doesn't outright recommend it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for respond. I don't saw it in help, could you please indicate where I can find it?